# Modifying Just One Series in Google Sheets Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

I have the following code which changes all series in a google sheets chart to have dashed lines:

```
function changeChart() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
chart = chart.modify()
 .setOption('lineDashStyle', [4,4])       
 .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

}

I want to just modify one series in the chart. Does anyone know how to select just one of the series to modify?

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
function changeChart() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
   .setOption("series", {
     0: {lineDashStyle: [4, 4]},
     1: {lineDashStyle: [1, 1]}
   })
   .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
}
```

In the case of EmbeddedChartBuilder, it uses "series" for "setOption()". 0 and 1 show each line.

Comment: @Tony That's good. If your question was solved, please push accepted button. If you push accepted button on this your question, everyone will be able to see this as a solved question. And also I'm glad. If you don't know about "accepted", please check this. http://stackoverflow.com/tour