# How to make a line chart dashed which gets updated with Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts, google-visualization

I have a chart in Google Sheets that gets updated with Google Apps Script when a button is hit. Here for example, the color of the lines change when the script is activated.

```
function change() {

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("sheet");

var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];

chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('colors', ['#3465a4', '#A2BEE2', '#76a5af', '#B2CCD2'])
          .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);

}
```

But I fail to implement a switch to a dashed line - and back again to a non-dashed line. It needs to be done via script, not manually.

I think this might be achieved with the 'security' role and 'uncertainty' attribute as it is documented here:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles?hl=de#stylerole
or with the lineDashStyle documented here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options?hl=de#line-config-options

```
chart = chart.modify()
     .setOption('lineDashStyle', [4,4]) 
          .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

But I fail to make it work.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please add a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying Just One Series in Google Sheets Chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42448363/modifying-just-one-series-in-google-sheets-chart)

Comment: I added the whole script for the chart

Comment: Are you still looking for an answer? Recently, I could find this option. So, I answered it. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to modify the existing chart as the line colors of `['#3465a4', '#A2BEE2', '#76a5af', '#B2CCD2']` and the dashed lines.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('colors', ['#3465a4', '#A2BEE2', '#76a5af', '#B2CCD2'])
          .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

##### To:

```js
chart = chart.modify()
  .setOption('colors', ['#3465a4', '#A2BEE2', '#76a5af', '#B2CCD2'])
  .setOption('series', {
    0: { lineDashType: 'mediumDash' },
    1: { lineDashType: 'mediumDash' },
    2: { lineDashType: 'mediumDash' },
    3: { lineDashType: 'mediumDash' },
  })
  .build();
sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

#### Testing:

When this script is run to a sample chart, the following result is obtained.

##### From:

[image]

##### To:

[image]

#### Note:

- By this, 4 lines are changed to the dashed line. In this case, it seems that there are the following 6 patterns.

  - `solid`, `dot`, `mediumDash`, `mediumDashDot`, `longDash`, `longDashDot`
- Also, you can use `.setOption('series.0.lineDashType', 'mediumDash')`.